# unable to click on radio button controls

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to dynamically copy some radio buttons but for some reason the cloned radio buttons cannot be selected... Can anyone help me?

#### HTML

```
   <div id="sGroup">
<div class="section" id="section1">
<input type="text" size = "16" id="section1" placeholder="Section Name"/>
<p id="par1"><textarea rows="2" cols="70" id="info1"/></textarea></p>
</div>
<div class="mediasection" id="mediasection1">
<input type="text" size ="50" id="url1" placeholder="Media URL"/>
<input type="radio" name ="media1" id="image1"/> Image
<input type="radio" name ="media1" id="video1"/> Video
</div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function addMedia() {
var clonemedia = $("mediasection1").cloneNode(true);
clonemedia.setAttribute("id", "mediasection"+secCount);
//mediasection1 and mediasection2
var allRadio = clonemedia.querySelectorAll("input");
allRadio[0].setAttribute("id", "url"+secCount);
allRadio[1].setAttribute("name", "media"+secCount);
allRadio[1].setAttribute("id", "image"+secCount);   
allRadio[2].setAttribute("name", "media"+secCount);
allRadio[2].setAttribute("id", "video"+secCount);
clonemedia.appendChild(allRadio[0]);
clonemedia.appendChild(allRadio[1]);
clonemedia.appendChild(allRadio[2]);
$("sGroup").appendChild(clonemedia);
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using? Prototype.js?

Comment: This creates the radio buttons for me and they're functional, [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUL9y/). What more are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is a really old question but in case people do discover this somehow it was because my div was on top of my radio buttons so I couldn't click them. The CSS which wasn't provided had one of my divs hidden so I didn't even know (my friend did the CSS and I did the javascript).